# streaming c++ program and shared libraries

Tags: c++, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a C++ program which I am trying to run as a streaming job on hadoop (it has only mappers, no reducers). While a simple C++ program works correctly. Another C++ program which links with lot of shared libraries is not working on the grid. ldd on this C++ program shows following: (it uses lot of third party libraries like opencv and boost_serialization)

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.48.0 /usr/local/lib/libfftw3f.so.3   /usr/local/lib/libconfig++.so.9 /usr/local/lib/liblog4cpp.so.4   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.3
```

I think because these shared libraries are not installed on data-nodes, its failing. I tried to put these libraries in a tarball and specified this to streaming job using -archives option (Distributed cache). This also did not work (I am not sure if contents from tarball were installed in the appropriate directory on data-nodes).

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: for future people who google this, PLEASE share with us your solution!

Comment: Actually everything was fine. I bundled all the third party libraries my application was using as a tarball and made it available to all data nodes using -archive streaming option. The problem was somehow the hadoop/MR was creating two mappers whereas I was providing just one file as input. So two output files were getting generated, one having size zero and other having the expected data. I figured out this by looking at the logs. Then I did a gzip of the single input file and used that for streaming. After this things worked fine. Got single output file.

Comment: I suggest that you write the answer yourself and mark it as the correct answer. By doing this people that are browsing for unanswered question won't end up here. (like me) :) It might also reward you with a badge and the answer will be easier to find!

Answer (score 0):

Compile your C++ program statically.  Basically:

```
g++ -o <progra> -static <object-files>
```

This will produce a binary that has no dependencies.  It will be bulky (run `strip` on it!) but if it runs continuously you shouldn't have a problem.